# Sites do not open up in Ubuntu when connected to a hotel Wi-Fi

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

So basically this is a problem I'm facing in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. When I connect to a hotel Wi-Fi which is a public Wi-Fi with their login page opening up, the login status page shows that I'm connected to the internet but when I try to open any page on Chrome, take for simplicity stackoverflow.com, what I get is a certificate error ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. I tried to open the page on some other browser but the certificate error still prevails. This happens literally on every site I tried. I tried to ping www.google.com on the terminal and I got the reply. What's most astonishing is that when I connect to the same Wi-Fi but in Windows 10(my laptop has dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04), there is no issue! Also, when I create a hotspot on my phone and connect to it on Ubuntu, there is no issue.

I tried to look for answers on stackoverflow and askubuntu but to no avail. Any help and possibly fixes to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly some proxy playing up. Tried with Firefox? Windows has a reg key to avoid this. See https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH240507.html

Comment: @xenoid Yes I tried it on FIrefox as well. It is showing an error related to certificate as well. I'll try the article you suggested and provide updates soon.